# Why is it said that maximum likelihood becomes intractable if there are latent variables?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, latent-variable

It is said that EM algorithm helps in cases where direct MLE cannot be carried out due to missing/latent variables. However, I could not understand why direct MLE cannot be carried out when there are latent variables.

$$ \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}\prod_{i}^{n}f\left(x_i|\theta\right) \sim  \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta} ln \left< \prod_{i}^{n}f\left(x_i|\theta\right) \right> =  \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta} \sum_{i}^{n} ln \left< f\left(x_i|\theta\right) \right> =$$
$$ \sum_{i}^{n} \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta} ln \left< f\left(x_i|\theta\right) \right> = 0 $$

Is it something related to the term $f\left(x_i|\theta\right>$?

**My Understanding:**

Data point $x_i$ is actually a collection of variable values. Example: if data point $x_i$ is house-metric, variables length, breadth, and height will define it: $x_i$=(400,500,200). In case there is a latent variable $V$ that affects $x_i$, $V$ cannot be properly defined in $x_i$ since $V$ cannot be observed. So, due to that $x_i$ will not be complete and $f\left(x_i|\theta\right>$ cannot be determined. Hence, MLE becomes intractable.

Is my understanding correct? Or is there a different / additional reason.

Comment: Hint: there is an expectation symbol $\langle \cdot \rangle$ in the expression you copied

Comment: @J.Delaney Not able to get my head around it even with the hint. Some more hint please?

Comment: Do you understand what this symbol represents and why it is there ?

Comment: My understanding is that the product of large number of probability densities can result in very small number (close to 0). So, in order to change product expression into sum, natural logarithm is used since argmax theta with the product expression or the ln result in the same value. Hence, natural logarithm is applied on the product. However, I do not know why <.> is available and its significance. @J.Delaney

Comment: Your understanding of why $\ln$ is used is correct, although not specifically related to the question.  The brackets represent expectation (integration) w.r.t the latent variables - and integrals can't always be calculated in closed form.

Comment: Why is expectation (integration) w.r.t the latent variables there? Could you please help me understand its significance? @J.Delaney

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136014/discussion-between-curious-and-j-delaney).

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct that we cannot observe the latent variable, therefore we need to use the EM algorithm. In the E step we estimate our distribution for the latent variable and In the M step we estimate the parameters that will minimize the KL divergence.

To be more clear you can think of $f\left(x|0\right)$ in your question, which I believe is the likelihood, as a joint distribution of $f\left(x,V,0\right)$. So, your term would be like $f(x|V,\theta)f(V|\theta)$. So, $x$ is now dependent on $V$ which you do not observe.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This can be handled fairly simply with Bayesian models.